# Create a new listview when a button is pressed in android

Tags: android, listview

I am a newbie to android programming

I have two listviews in my activity and two buttons. If I press first button one listview will be created and shown in the activity and when the second button is clicked the second listview is created and first one should be closed.

Can anyone suggest me how to do this??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: So do you want us to write the code for displaying ListView on onClickListener method ?? Kindly explain briefly that what do u want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using fragments. Use a frame layout in your main activity. Then depending on the user choice load one of the fragment dynamically.

```
case (R.id.button1):
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, frag1);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
break;
```

See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html && http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html

Comment: can you please post some example or tutorials related to your solution?

Answer (score 1):

The easy option will be to change the list adapter on a list at runtime on button click.

like

```
on first button click

    list.setAdapter(adapter1);

on second button click 

    list.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

And You can use tabs also to show two lists
See this example for

http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=59

and

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/tab-control/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very much like a Tab interface. So this should be easy with

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#newTab()

The documentation there has a full implementation example using fragments. You might not have used fragments before but don't fear, they are basically just views. Get the example working before trying to get the listviews flying around.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

While i pressed second button

```
       firstlistView.setVisibility(1);(1->Invisible state)first listview goes invisible state
       secondlistview.setVisiblity(0);(0->Visible)Ur second listview shown by this code
```

Answer (score 0):

if u want to display two list on two different button,you can use just one list with two different 
ArrayAdapter and change list.

sample code...

**Put this code in your xml file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="List1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="List2" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Put this code in your Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView1;
    Button list1Button,list2Button;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1,adapter2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        list1Button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        list2Button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

       String[] names1 = {"Android","Iphone","Titenium"};
       String[] names2 = {"java",".net","php"};

       adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names1);
       adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names2);

       listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);

       list1Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            listView1.setAdapter(null);

            listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);

        }
    });

       list2Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            listView1.setAdapter(null);
            listView1.setAdapter(adapter2);
        }
    });

    }




}
```

i hope this may help you..